# React filter button counts

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have:

```
var RightPanel = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function () {
        this.load();
    },
    load: function(){

    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="controls col-xs-6">
                        <span className="title">Filters</span>

                        <FilterButton name='My jobs' count={this.props.counts.my_jobs} active={this.props.active}/>
                        <FilterButton name='Not approved' count={this.props.counts.not_approved}/>
                        <FilterButton name='Supply' count={this.props.counts.supply}/>
                        <FilterButton name='Repair' count={this.props.counts.repair}/>
                        <FilterButton name='Service exchange' count={this.props.counts.service_ex}/>
                        <FilterButton name='Urgent' count={this.props.counts.urgent}/>
                        <FilterButton name='Today' count={this.props.counts.today}/>
                        <FilterButton name='Overdue' count={this.props.counts.overdue}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="controls">
                    <span className="title">Analysis</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

var FilterButton = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <button className={'btn btn-filter btn-sm'+(this.props.active ? ' active' : '')}><span
                className="filter-name">My jobs</span><span className="filter-count">{this.props.count}</span></button>
        )
    }
})
```

But I don't know what the correct way is to load in the counts for my buttons. At the moment if I try to define a test object it tells me it is undefined:

```
...
load: function(){
    this.props.counts = [
        {my_jobs: 1},
        {not_approved: 5}
    ]
},
...
```

How do I get this to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `state` instead of props. Look at `props` object as immutable object that you can't change anyway. Option that can help you is use `getInitialState` that set default state to you.

Let's improve your code:

```
var RightPanel = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            counts: {}
        }
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        this.load();
    },
    //if you need to change state while get new props use this method
    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        if(newProps.counts) {
             this.setState({
                 counts: newProps.counts
              });
        }
    },
    load: function(){
        this.setState({
            counts: {
                 my_jobs: 1,
                 not_approved: 5
            }
        }); //in this moment your component will rerender
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="controls col-xs-6">
                        <span className="title">Filters</span>

                        <FilterButton name='My jobs' count={this.state.counts.my_jobs || 0} active={this.props.active}/>
                        <FilterButton name='Not approved' count={this.state.counts.not_approved || 0}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="controls">
                    <span className="title">Analysis</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use props to pass to its child,
it should be like this or use defaultProps.

```
let counts = [...];
<RightPanel counts={counts}/>
```

componentDidMount can't load props.